# Using servo motors without PWM

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, servo

I’m new to the ATmega32 and I want to connect 4 servo motors to a single ATmega32 chip without using PWM pins.

Is this possible? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: Are you fine with bit-banging your own PWM signals given that you don't want to use the PWM pins?

Comment: You can also use a shift register and just one PWM pin, which is what receivers do in model RC.

Comment: _"I want to connect 4 servo motors to a single Atmega32 chip without using PWM pins"_ - Why?

Comment: @DKNguyen That single-wire signal is not a simple PWM. There needs to be a pause between the pulse trains to synchronize the channels.

Comment: @thebusybee Technically, none of the "PWM" in RC is  actually PWM either but a better name was never given for it. But you can still use one-shot modes in the PWM to trigger the shift register, or just timer interrupts.

Comment: @DKNguyen Right, the term was rather "digital-proportional control", IIRC. Anyway, as you say, one could use a PWM signal of appropriate ratio to mimick the signal for a single servo. My point is that it cannot be done for multiple servos over a single wire as model RC does.

Comment: @thebusybee Are we talking about the same thing? The shift register is the one that connects to multiple servos and is driven from one wire by the MCU to produce the right pulse to propagate for the servos. You basically propagate the same pulse from servo to servo in the shift register but move it to the next servo at the right time so they each see their appropriate control width/timing.

Comment: @DKNguyen Yes, I'm sure we are. [This is a time diagram](https://www.avrfreaks.net/sites/default/files/PulseTrain.jpg) of the pulse train (top row) expected by the shift register, which is BTW not a simple shift register. A PWM hardware component of an AVR cannot produce this pulse train without complex software.

Comment: Yes, we are talking about the same thing then.